# How to export Tree object from Rich library to a text(.txt) file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, rich

Is there anyway to export tree object from Rich?

```
from rich.tree import Tree
from rich import print as rprint

tree = Tree("Family Tree")
tree.add("Mom")
tree.add("Dad")
tree.add("Brother").add("Wife")
tree.add("[red]Sister").add("[green]Husband").add("[blue]Son")

rprint(tree)
```

I need to export the tree as a text file from `rprint(tree)` result. (***Ignore the colors***)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rich.print` uses the same syntax as print so you can write directly to an object with a write method. E.g.

```
with open('my_tree.txt', 'w') as f:
    rprint(tree, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I used terminal to append the print result to a text file:

```
$ python my_family.py  >> my_family.txt
```

any idea to do it from Python?